# Oracle condition checking

Tags: sql, oracle

how to check this in where clause

This should return false
'thousand'='usa'

This should return false
'canada','tower'='canada'

This should return true
'south','africa'='south africa'

Comment: What is `strname`? If it's a table column what does it's data actually look like?

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. Also, post the code you already tried, clearly explaining what's wrong with it.

Comment: You need to structure your question in such a way that it is clear what 'strname' is, e.g. table column, variable and what it is you actually want to achieve. If you can pose a question in an understandable way you may find that the answer becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( strname ) AS 
  SELECT '''canada'',''tower''' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '''south'',''africa''' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  strname LIKE '%''' || lower( 'canada' ) || '''%'
```

**Output**:

```
STRNAME
----------------
'canada','tower'
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  strname LIKE '%''' || lower( 'south' ) || '''%'
AND    strname LIKE '%''' || lower( 'africa' ) || '''%'
```

**Output**:

```
STRNAME
----------------
'south','africa'
```

Comment: This answer is based on the OP's [original version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43627695/3).